# Formatting a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want this:

```
        SP,1,2,3
        1,1.000000e+00,2.000000e+00,3.000000e+00
        2,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
        3,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
        4,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
```

I have the following code:

```
np.savetxt("Final Array.csv", my_array, fmt="%10.6e", delimiter=',')
```

It produces:

```
    1.000000e+00,2.000000e+00,3.000000e+00
    1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
    1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
    1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
```

I already have the arrays created for the top row and the left column.

How do I format this so that I can keep the numbers formatted correctly while still having the left most column, and the top row stay formatted as they are?

I am using vstack and hstack to combine these, but the "SP" is also causing problems because it isn't a float.

Could I maybe format them, convert it all to a string, combine and then savetxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution requires to create a temporary array with the same length as `my_array` and an extra column.

```
temp = np.empty((my_array.shape[0], my_array.shape[1]+1))
```

Then, fill the first column with the indices you want, and the last columns with your initial array:

```
temp[:,1:] = my_array
temp[:,0] = np.arange(1, len(my_array)+1)
```

In order to write the header, you have to open the file in writing first. You can still pass the file object to `np.savetxt`, you just have to modify the format string so that your first column is written as `int`, the others as `"%10.6e"`:

```
with open('final.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("SP,1,2,3\n")
    np.savetxt(f, temp, fmt="%i,%10.6e,%10.6e,%10.6e",delimiter=",")
```

A more interactive way to define your format string, depending on the number of columns of `my_array` is

```
fmt = ",".join(["%i"] + ["%10.6e"] * my_array.shape[1])
np.savetxt(f, temp, fmt=fmt, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: is there a way I can make only the first one i% and then all consecutive ones %10.6e? the problem is that the array can be a variable size.

Comment: How come you have strings in your array?!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
 from cStringIO import StringIO
 from itertools import izip

 # savetxt into a string
 sio = StringIO()
 np.savetxt(sio, my_array, fmt="%10.6e", delimeter=',')
 data_lines = sio.getvalue().split('\n')

 with open('Final Array.csv', 'w') as f:
     f.write(header_string + '\n')
     for leftcol, main in izip(left_column, data_lines):
         f.write(leftcol + ',' + main)
```

Or to do it without `savetxt` at all:

```
with open('Final Array.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(header_string + '\n')
    for label, row in izip(left_column, my_array):
        f.write(str(label) + ',' + ','.join('%10.6e' % x for x in row) + '\n')
```