# Adding Header to Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

I have an array I would like to add a header for.

This is what i have now:

```
0.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
1.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
2.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
```

This is what i want:

```
SP,1,2,3
0.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
1.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
2.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01
```

Notes: 
"SP" will always be 1st followed by the numbering of the columns which may vary

here is my existing code:

```
fmt = ",".join(["%s"] + ["%10.6e"] * (my_array.shape[1]-1))

np.savetxt('final.csv', my_array, fmt=fmt,delimiter=",")
```

Comment: You already have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218945/formatting-numpy-array/12219132#12219132), why asking again ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note:** this answer was written for an older version of numpy, relevant when the question was written. With modern numpy, [makhlaghi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16520086/1600898) provides a more elegant solution.

Since `numpy.savetxt` can also write to file objects, you can open the file youself and write your header before the data:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[0.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01],
                 [1.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01],
                 [2.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01]])
fmt = ",".join(["%s"] + ["%10.6e"] * (a.shape[1]-1))

# numpy.savetxt, at least as of numpy 1.6.2, writes bytes
# to file, which doesn't work with a file open in text mode.  To
# work around this deficiency, open the file in binary mode, and
# write out the header as bytes.
with open('final.csv', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(b'SP,1,2,3\n')
  #f.write(bytes("SP,"+lists+"\n","UTF-8"))
  #Used this line for a variable list of numbers
  numpy.savetxt(f, a, fmt=fmt, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Using this code i get the following error:

File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1009, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

@user4815162342

Comment: I've now corrected the answer to work in Python 3, tested with Python 3.2.3.

Answer (score 44):

Ever since Numpy 1.7.0, three parameters have been added to [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for exactly this purpose: header, footer and comments. So the code to do as you wanted can easily be written as:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[0.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01],
                 [1.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01],
                 [2.0,1.630000e+01,1.990000e+01,1.840000e+01]])
fmt = ",".join(["%s"] + ["%10.6e"] * (a.shape[1]-1))
numpy.savetxt("temp", a, fmt=fmt, header="SP,1,2,3", comments='')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to save other things than `numpy` arrays to file using the   [`savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) or [`savez_compressed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) functions. Using [`load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) function you can retrieve all data like it was pickled like a dict.

```
import numpy as np

np.savez("filename.npz", array_to_save=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), header="Some header")

data = np.load("filename.npz")
array = data["array_to_save"]
header = str(data["header"])
```