# Creating columns after converting list to an array

Tags: python, numpy

My question is how do I convert the first four columns to floats and the last column to string? the kicker is that I cant use Pandas or CSV, I can only use numpy. How would I go about this? I have converted list into an array and currently displays:

**'5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa'**

I need to add the proper column headings as well, any input would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

training_data = open("C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\iris-training-data.csv")
training_data_list = []

for elements in training_data:
    training_data_list.append(elements)


training_data_array = np.array(training_data_list)

print "The shape is {}\n".format(training_data_array.shape)

print "The visual array is: {}".format(training_data_array)
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219132/6438896

Comment: Is that one row of many? I'm assuming they are trying to get you to use a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) so that you can have mixed dtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, a fundamental part of `numpy` is that its arrays are homogeneous (each element has exactly the same type).

If you need an extra row (such as headings) or a column (as your last column that is a string) with a different type, you will have to keep them in separate numpy arrays.

You can convert the numeric part of your input from string to float using the `astype` method, e.g.:

```
string_col = traninig_data_array[:,4] # the last column
numbers = training_data_array[:,:4].astype(dtype=np.float64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import csv
with open('path_to_csv', newline='') as file:
data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
for row in data:
    row = row[0].split(',')
    r = [float(item) for item in row[:4]]
    r.append(str(row[4]))
    print(r)
```

This is my output, but I ran it for 9 columns rather than your 5. But it is same data set. The code I have put out will work for you.

```
[7.2, 0.805555556, 3.0, 0.416666667, 5.8, 0.813559322, 1.6, 0.625, 'virginica']
[7.4, 0.861111111, 2.8, 0.333333333, 6.1, 0.86440678, 1.9, 0.75, 'virginica']
[7.9, 0.9999, 3.8, 0.75, 6.4, 0.915254237, 2.0, 0.791666667, 'virginica']
[6.4, 0.583333333, 2.8, 0.333333333, 5.6, 0.779661017, 2.2, 0.875, 'virginica']
[6.3, 0.555555556, 2.8, 0.333333333, 5.1, 0.694915254, 1.5, 0.583333333, 'virginica']
```

Comment: well this would work but I cant import CSV, the only import I can do is NUMPY

Comment: So you can only use numpy?

Comment: @Onecam you should mention these restrictions in your question. The csv module is part of the standard library, there's no reason for us to assume you can't use it.

Comment: yeah @jack, nothing else. that is why its complicated

Comment: @rogan, you are correct sir, my apologies, I have updated my post

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.char.html) ?